# Using variable inside SqlDataSource's ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In the code behind:

```
public static string constring = main_class.con_string;
```

In the markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="BooksRecordTableSource" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%= constring %>">
```

but this is showing an error

[image: Error]

Comment: Is there any other way to use references?

Comment: You can try setting the connection string of SqlDataSource in the code behind. In Page_Load method.

Comment: Correct format is `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyCnn %>"` where MyCnn is ConnectionString name in `web.config`. Else set connectionString property of your `SqlDataSource` as early as possible (`Page_PreInit`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

1. Use the SQLDataSource OnInit event to call a method in the code behind:
2. Friend Sub SQLDataSource_OnInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Dim sqlDS As SqlDataSource = sender
       sqlDS.ConnectionString = Globals.s_DBConnection
   End Sub